# Scraping a web page from a website built with React and jQuery

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I need to extract the product name, price and default color from the following link:
[Link](http://%3Chttps://shop.mango.com/gb/women/skirts-midi/midi-satin-skirt_17042020.html?c=99%3E)

However, every time I load the below script the information is retrieved differently (sometimes all three values are printed, sometimes 1-2 of them or none). This happens regardless of WebDriverWait.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
#import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://shop.mango.com/gb/women/skirts-midi/midi-satin-skirt_17042020.html?c=99')

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)

s = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
name = s.select('.product-name')[0].getText()
price = s.select('.product-sale')[0].getText()
color = s.select('.colors-info')[0].getText()
print(name, price, color)
```

Would you please advise how to extract all three elements? If I try to download the page with requests or scrapy the above elements are missing.

Comment: You are using beautoful soup not Selenium to extract the items. So webdriverwait won't have any impact on it.

Comment: @cruisepandey  it was the same with selenium:

```
browser.get('https://shop.mango.com/gb/women/skirts-midi/midi-satin-skirt_17042020.html?c=99')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)
name = browser.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
price = browser.find_element_by_class_name('product-sale').text
color = browser.find_element_by_class_name('colors-info').text
product = {'name': name,
           'price': price,
           'color': color
}
with open('product5.json','w') as product_dumped :
    json.dump(product,product_dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points :

1. There's an accept cookies button, which you have to click in order to proceed further.
2. After cookies button there is a modal close button, which we have to click in order to proceed further.
3. Use Explicit waits, visibility of element for this case.
4. Prefer `CSS` over `xpath`.
5. Maximize the browser.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://shop.mango.com/gb/women/skirts-midi/midi-satin-skirt_17042020.html?c=99')

try:
    print("to accept cookies")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
except:
    pass

try:
    print("to close modal pop up windows")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='closeModal'][class$='confirmacionPais']"))).click()
except:
    pass


name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-name'))).text
price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-sale'))).text
color = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'colors-info'))).text

print(name, price, color)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
to accept cookies
to close modal pop up windows
Midi satin skirt £39.99 Black
```